# Why font-size defined at :root is overriden by user agent stylesheet? If it's intended to be, then how is th snippet supposed to work?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, font-size, css-specificity

My understanding is that the CSS in the following snippet is for having `font-size` vary gradually with the viewport, a possiple building block to accomplish responsive design:

```css
:root {
  font-size: calc(.6em + 1vw);
}
```

```html
<html lang="it">
  <body>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    text
  </body>
</html>
```

The devtools, however, show me that `font-size: calc(.6em + 1vw);` is overridden (and show like this: <s>`font-size: calc(.6em + 1vw);`</s>) by the following ruleset of the user agent stylesheet

```css
h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    /* and other stuff */
}
```

Why does this happen?

The `:root { font-size: calc(.6em + 1vw); }` ruleset is not my invention, so it ought to work, and I think I'm just misusing/misunderstanding it.

My understanding is that the `:root` selector targets the same object as the `html` selector, but with class specificity rather than tag specificity. Given this, I'd expect that the user agent stylesheet's `h1 {}` ruleset can't override it.

Comment: em means using the font-size of the parent as reference, so your h1 is having `2*(0.6*16px + 1vw)`

Comment: It's bothering me a little bit that the lang is set to it but the example text is clearly English lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because following style

```
:root { font-size: calc(.6em + 1vw); }
```

in the case of `h1`, is just an **inherited** style.
Any styles applied directly to the element will override inherited styles, which is exactly what the user agent is doing with `h1 { font-size: 2em;}`

If you want to inherit the root style, you can explicitly set:

```
h1 {
   font-size: inherit; 
}
```

In this case both you and the user agent apply the style directly and yours will win since it has same specificity and it's loaded after the other.
But the problem with this approach is that if `<body>`or any closest parent has an explicit `font-size` it'll inherit that instead of root.

Imo this whole situation is much better handled by a CSS variable.

```css
:root {
  --font-size: calc(.6em + 1vw);
}

h1 {
  font-size: var(--font-size);
}
```

```html
<html lang="it">

<body>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  text
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Oh, so the fact that the devtools shows the ruleset `font-size: calc(.6em + 1vw);` struck out doesn't mean that thing is having no effect, it just means it's the base value on which a relative value is computed!